Question on Descartes’ solution to Pappus' problem
One of Descartes' great contributions to mathematics is the development of analytical geometry, and one of the problems that lead him to his discovery was the so called Pappus problem: or the three and four line locus problem.   It states that given three of four lines and a point of which lines extend to the given lines at given angles, satisfy a ratio that the product of two given lines is proportional to the square of the third (three line problem) or the product of two given lines is proportional to the other two given lines (four line problem).  The result is meant to be an indeterminate equation that traces the conic sectoins.  My question is do the angles stay fixed for each solution?

A complete document here : https://sidoli.w.waseda.jp/Bos_Pappus_Problem.pdf

Descartes gives his solution of the problem of Pappus on pp. 59-80 of La Geometrie (tr. Smith & Latham, Dover edition, 1954). As shown in the figures there, each of the four lines $CB$, $CD$, $CF$, $CH$ makes a given angle with $AB$, $AD$, $EF$, $GH$, respectively— different perhaps for each line but fixed for each of them.
As he says (p. 60), “let it be required to find the locus generated by a point $C$, such that, if four lines $CB$, $CD$, $CF$, and $CH$ be drawn through it making given angles with the given lines, the product of $CB$ and $CF$ is equal to the product of $CD$ and $CH$.”
Since $C$ is a locus of points, the angle each line makes with its respective given line is fixed. E.g. for every point on the locus (i.e. every solution), $CD$ makes the same angle with $AD$.
